hosting streamlit app on apache server on windows 10
I've an app developed using streamlit. I'm trying to host this app using apache server on windows 10. I'm new to this and not able to understand what files would be required and what modifications need to be done.
So far I've accomplished creating apache server and able to browse to localhost at port 8080.
How should I proceed to make this app available on browser. Looking for guidance please.
Thank you.
